"You’ve been doing this before." vs. "You've done this before." / What is the difference in this context?

I find it extraordinary that my father’s 120 acres not only supported a wide range of livestock but also enabled him to do arable farming. From earliest childhood I can remember him growing wheat, barley and oats. He had never received any formal training in agriculture but had acquired a flair for judging seed corn. I would watch him get out the well-honed pocket knife and slice a single grain and judge whether it would make good quality seed. He could sift through a sample and, hawk eyed, spot weeds. Over thirty years later he did the same on the farm of a Shropshire neighbor, John Gittins at Ruyton-XI-Towns. He had not lost his touch: “Here”, said John, “you’ve been doing this before.” During the Second World War he had to put more land under the plough and grew clover and sugar beet.

Semi-Detached by John Biffen

“I can’t to take this money, brother,” I said as he tossed the money in my lap. “This will save me, but what about you. I cannot by my happiness at the cost of pushing you into trouble.”
“Listen, Paarth! I know what I am doing. My father is out of town for fifteen days. I’ll figure out ten thousand different ways to cover this.”
“In case that doesn’t happen, he will throw you out of the house. You do know that?” I said.
“You don’t have to think about that. I am not stealing his money for the first time, you see”, he said ever so casually.
“You have been doing this before as well?” I asked, shocked.
This wasn’t the Kartik I thought I knew inside out.

Our Story of Love by Keshav Aneel
I have just one simple question: what would be the difference in the sentences above if instead of the Present Perfect Continuous were the Present Perfect Simple (“Hear”, said John, “you’ve done this before.” / “You have done this before as well?” I asked, shocked.)
I've always seen in the situations like these the Present Perfect used, never the Present Perfect Continuous! So, this seems to be confusing for me.

I'm a native speaker, and offhand I can't think of any context where you’ve been doing this before might be "better" than you done this before (Ngrams not found: You've been doing this before.). Bear in mind John Biffen's claim to fame is as a politician, not as a writer. Certainly for learners, the only sensible advice is Use the simplest verb form that makes sense.

As a general rule, "You’ve been doing this before" refers to an ongoing habit like farming. "You've done this before" refers to one thing you once did. That thing could be farming, or pulling one dandelion.

@YosefBaskin: That sounds like stretching a point to justify the usage. It's true I found you've been doing this before school even started in a Google Books search. But honestly, why introduce the Pointless Perfect? Just you were doing this before school even started must always mean exactly the same thing, obviously. For farming, You farmed before is all you need (no Perfect or Continuous), and You have been farming before is decidedly peculiar.

Actually, I've just realized it would be a typical "Indian English" usage. And I'd bet any money Keshav Aneel is Indian.

@FumbleFingers The speaker is from Shropshire. There's not a whit of Indian English in the entire paragraph.

@Lambie: Do keep up! I'm talking about the second cite in my last comment!

@YosefBaskin If I understand correctly,  "You’ve been doing this before." emphasizes the duration of an action while "You've done this before." emphasizes an event. If so, is this sentence correct:  "I've been doing farming several times before." - to emphasize that what I've done has lasted for some time?

There's also a temporal clash between present perfect continuous have been doing and before that is not idiomatic in standard English.  before means "before now", thus casting the action of the verb in the past.   "You've been doing this for quite some time, I see." or something like it is what would be idiomatic in standard English. Or "I see you've done this before."


Yes, duration as opposed to event.  2) I wouldn't use "I've been farming several times before." Maybe "I've been farming barley (or by hand) several times before."


@TimR So, if I may ask, you disagree with Yosef Baskin on this one? You think it's wrong to say  "I've been farming barley (or by hand) several times before." or  “Here”, said John, “you’ve been doing this before.”?

@MickeyQ I understood Yosef to be focusing on the difference between the present perfect continuous and the present perfect. But if he would also claim that before is idiomatic with the present perfect continuous in standard BrE or  standard AmE,  I'd have to disagree.

@TimR Thanks! What do you think would be the reason to use "before" with the Present Perfect Continuous in the OP excerpts? Do you have any idea as to what the authors wanted to express by this unidiomatic construction?

@MickeyQ  That speaker doesn't feel the aspect-clash in "have been doing it before". The intended meaning is "I can see you're no novice at this but have done it multiple times in the past."  As we say, "I can see you're an old hand at this."

In simpler terms, "You’ve been doing this before." suggests that someone has been doing the same thing repeatedly in the past, implying a habit or pattern. On the other hand, "You've done this before." simply acknowledges that the action has happened at least once in the past without indicating whether it was repeated. In the context given, the first phrase implies ongoing or habitual behavior, while the second phrase asks about a single occurrence in the past. Both are grammatically correct but convey different aspects of the person's past actions.
